# Cypress How can I get length of API response data?

Tags: json, api, response, cypress

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMwwK.png)

Cypress How can I get length of API response data?
I want to check length of this api call response which is in json format
Please See above Image

`

```js
body: Array(42)
0: {id: "85ae44da-d8f0-42a3-b43a-084689fe1586", displayName: "PARTIE-323-1", description: "PARTIE-323-1", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
1: {id: "953f1b5a-6cb1-4c9c-92c1-0bf99e527330", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 5", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
2: {id: "4522cb19-27db-497f-8489-0c48f121cecd", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 13", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
3: {id: "bb25ea81-8d09-4679-9c54-0fb082a96ad5", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 98", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
4: {id: "a5110f81-438d-4f11-ab01-153e8a5f84a0", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 86", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
5: {id: "48d0ce7a-0408-4ec8-bc08-1c1b74ec25c7", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 410", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
6: {id: "f7a6db8c-2e0e-4e33-87d6-1f1339c9abec", displayName: " Edit Mesage Number 5094", description: " Edit Mesage Number 5094", tags: "PvP,Mic On"}
7: {id: "c78bc55c-2341-4d3b-acf1-275d457cc750", displayName: "Kashif4 Partie rrrr", description: "Kashfi4 OBJ", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
8: {id: "b1146736-d56e-414b-92c1-3060ca5b1c7c", displayName: "BY_DN4", description: "OBJ1", tags: "PvE"}
9: {id: "8feb702d-6ed2-4c2d-9008-3414da968ed2", displayName: "abcdef", description: "abc", tags: "PvE"}
10: {id: "5e593e21-aff3-40ce-9cac-3707943aeb01", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 1711", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
11: {id: "6a9a4183-0a66-4749-9e98-55c988458a3d", displayName: "ratinfff", description: "vxvcxvc", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
12: {id: "74b93d2a-08bb-4568-9fd0-56f64166af4c", displayName: "patrie2000", description: "patrie2000", tags: "PvE"}
13: {id: "18e03e40-7fc4-4e75-a996-597190ca2387", displayName: "PARTIE-287 1", description: "PARTIE-287 1", tags: "PvE"}
14: {id: "e2cf2a81-4a06-4dc3-8694-59dbda0b926a", displayName: "adfasdfsadd", description: "adfasdfsadd", tags: "PvE"}
15: {id: "83cc93b1-57e0-490c-88e5-5a73d6d89137", displayName: "This is Partie Number 1544", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
16: {id: "b1157576-e658-4a30-9ced-65d9bd9d8640", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 55", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
17: {id: "8ea1aaf8-07c7-4ab7-985f-717495447e8b", displayName: "New Partie", description: "abc", tags: "PvE"}
18: {id: "da83f044-7e11-40a8-967e-7c11593dd16f", displayName: "This is Partie Number 978", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
19: {id: "130607fc-c488-49aa-a262-7dd5cd81621c", displayName: "lllllklklklklk;lkl", description: "fffffffffffffff", tags: "PvE"}
20: {id: "4f56bd15-fb3d-457f-a003-88cd8a866eba", displayName: "rating", description: "aa", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
21: {id: "8cf069fc-b917-4a41-8368-94235b9c2dca", displayName: "test ", description: "abc", tags: "PvE"}
22: {id: "d5db750c-1eed-4662-b98f-98514224771f", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 1505", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
23: {id: "186e5927-4044-4bc4-ab84-9d0284bf9e2e", displayName: "This is post with 50 characters This is post with 50 characters This is post with 50 characters This", description: "This is post with 50 characters This is post with …is post with 50 characters This is post with 50 c", tags: "PvE"}
24: {id: "6b5a9841-c769-47aa-81d8-a471492b4268", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 66", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
25: {id: "e23918cb-4119-4ff2-bafd-a4fba328dbf5", displayName: "wret", description: "afdasf", tags: "PvP"}
26: {id: "d1e51372-229a-44db-9214-a8964f29fefe", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 870", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
27: {id: "84b10103-a123-47af-b266-ad96f4b0967b", displayName: "aa", description: "afasd", tags: "PvE"}
28: {id: "15af3152-408e-4ba5-8fe5-af5ac6bb2615", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 65", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
29: {id: "8b05fd09-30c3-4a1f-be10-af830de98e63", displayName: "abcdef", description: "abc", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
30: {id: "b35eab58-a35d-4923-89cf-b56b0b96f921", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 1737", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
31: {id: "6ce5e08c-4a5b-4c12-a409-c0d620b2e823", displayName: "commences paritie toaster", description: "commences paritie toaster", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
32: {id: "0916cace-a136-4459-b224-c7fdc90fed36", displayName: "This is Partie Number 509", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
33: {id: "774b859c-7d17-4086-8739-ccf575780de2", displayName: "partie 1 for cypress test", description: "partie 1 for cypress test", tags: "PvE"}
34: {id: "8e648113-09dc-4cc8-9c0f-d88912bb798c", displayName: "Partie258147", description: "Partie258147", tags: "PvE"}
35: {id: "529d17d7-9bba-44cd-9720-df12ee596662", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 94", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
36: {id: "3a3871c0-49bd-46f3-9710-e3ff36ca239a", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 86", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
37: {id: "8e0712ec-ac60-4ffb-819a-eae7cd06aba8", displayName: "duplicate avatar", description: "abc", tags: "PvE"}
38: {id: "4cbf023d-d751-40e6-861e-ef65d4a46d2a", displayName: "This is Partie Number 1772", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
39: {id: "87929893-af9f-4544-98e2-f4f5bc798ad6", displayName: "This is Public Partie Number 481", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
40: {id: "2b9769d0-5860-483b-9482-f56d4f5dc9d6", displayName: "commences paritie toaster 2", description: "abc", tags: "PvE,PvP"}
41: {id: "1c365027-b86b-442f-92b8-fccf7e743155", displayName: "This is Partie Number 1653", description: "this is objective", tags: "PvE"}
length: 42
```

`

Cypress How can I get length of API response data?
I want to check length of this api call response which is in json format
Please See above Image

Comment: In javascript, simply call `.length` on the object. May you show us how theses console.log are done: what is your source code?

Comment: Since that is just an array you should be to assert that that has length of 42. You should be able to pull that off the BODY..

Comment: If the length will increase, won't your test fail because of that? Can you show us the code to call this API, or your current test.. I want to help, but I would need more information..

Comment: @Kashif you'll need to show your test code for to be able to help you

Comment: What exactly is failing? There's a lot going on...

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure out where the code in your repo is failing. You should make the smallest reproducible case, and either post the code to SO, or make a repo (your current repo contains too much unrelated code, and is communicating with real server).

Comment: StackOverflow -- I meant to put it in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am successful

```js
describe("Partie Counts Profile Page Test", () => {
  before(function() {
    cy.SignIn();
    cy.fixture("vars.json").as("vars");
  });

  it("Partie Counts", () => {
    const profileBtn = "div.actions--left > button > img";

    ///// I want to get lenght of the parties from the url response and want check with counts in UI
    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.get(profileBtn).click();
    cy.wait(1000);

    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      method: "GET",
      url: "api/v1/room/getUserRooms/d23eef09-e4e1-455d-a74c-03dfc61bde11"
    }).as("get_jobs");
    
    cy.wait("@get_jobs").then(xhr => {
      cy.log(xhr.response.body.length);
      cy.get("div:nth-child(3) > span.quick-stat-figure").should(
        "contain",
        xhr.response.body.length
      );
    });
  });
});
```